# Why can this product of rectangular matrices not be the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $m > n$ be positive integers. Show that there do not exist matrices $A ∈ R_{m×n}$ and $B ∈ R_{n×m}$ such that $AB = I_m$, where $I_m$ is the $m × m$ identity matrix

If someone could explain it with an example, it will be appreciable.

Comment: Hint: Look at the rank of each of the matrices.

Comment: What is $R$ in the question? Two possibilities would be suggested (1) the field of real numbers (prefer writing $\Bbb R$ then), or (2) some (commutative?) ring. The kind of answer that would be appropriate rather depends on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a classic result that if $f\circ g$ is a bijective map then $f$ is surjective and $g$ is an injective map, hence using this and assuming the existence of $B$ we see that  the linear transformation
$$f\colon\Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^m,\quad x\mapsto Ax$$
is surjective i.e $\operatorname{Im}g=\Bbb R^m$. Moreover by the rank-nullity theorem we have
$$\dim\Bbb R^n=n\ge\dim\operatorname{Im}g=m$$
which contradicts the hypothesis $n<m$. Conclude.

Comment: Excellent: answers the question, and more!

Answer (score 3):

Each column of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$, and each row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the columns of $B$. So $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \dim(\operatorname{colspace}(AB))\leqslant\operatorname{rank}(A)$, and $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \dim(\operatorname{rowspace}(AB))\leqslant\operatorname{rank}(B)$. So $\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leqslant\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B))\leqslant\min\{m,n\} = n < m$, but $\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(I_m) = m$. Contradiction.